# How can we determine whether a socket is ready to read/write?

Tags: sockets

How can we determine whether a socket is ready to **read/write** in socket programming.

Comment: You can use `select()` or `(e)poll` to query the socket's readability/writability states

Comment: Needs a language tag.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, use [select()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) or [poll()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html).

On Windows, you can use [WSAPoll()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsapoll) or [select()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-select), both from winsock2.

Mac OS X also has [select()](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/select.2.html) and [poll()](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/poll.2.html).

> #include <sys/select.h>
>
> int select(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds,
> fd_set *exceptfds, struct timeval *timeout);

> select() and pselect() allow a program to monitor multiple file descriptors, waiting until one or more of the file descriptors become "ready" for some class of I/O operation (e.g., input possible). A file descriptor is considered ready if it is possible to perform the corresponding I/O operation (e.g., read(2)) without blocking. – https://linux.die.net/man/3/fd_set

> #include <poll.h>

> int poll(struct pollfd *fds, nfds_t nfds, int timeout);
>
> poll() performs a similar task to select(2): it waits for one of a set of file descriptors to become ready to perform I/O.
> – https://linux.die.net/man/2/poll

Example of select usage:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main(void)
{
    fd_set rfds;
    struct timeval tv;
    int retval;

   /* Watch stdin (fd 0) to see when it has input. */
    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(0, &rfds);

   /* Wait up to five seconds. */
    tv.tv_sec = 5;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

   retval = select(1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    /* Don't rely on the value of tv now! */

   if (retval == -1)
        perror("select()");
    else if (retval)
        printf("Data is available now.\n");
        /* FD_ISSET(0, &rfds) will be true. */
    else
        printf("No data within five seconds.\n");

   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**Explanation of the above code:**

`FD_ZERO` initializes the `rfds` set. `FD_SET(0, &rfds)` adds fd 0 (stdin) to the set. `FD_ISSET` can be used to check whether a specific file descriptor is ready after select returns.

The select call in this example waits until rfds has input or until 5 seconds passes. The two `NULL`s in the select call are where file descriptor sets (`fd_set`s) to be checked for ready to write status and exceptions, respectively, would be passed. The `tv` argument is the number of seconds and microseconds to wait. The first argument to select, `nfds`, is the highest numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets (read, write, exceptions sets) plus one.

Example of poll usage (from [man7.org](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)):

```
/* poll_input.c

   Licensed under GNU General Public License v2 or later.
*/
#include <poll.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define errExit(msg)    do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); \
                        } while (0)

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int nfds, num_open_fds;
    struct pollfd *pfds;

    if (argc < 2) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file...\n", argv[0]);
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    num_open_fds = nfds = argc - 1;
    pfds = calloc(nfds, sizeof(struct pollfd));
    if (pfds == NULL)
        errExit("malloc");

    /* Open each file on command line, and add it 'pfds' array. */

    for (int j = 0; j < nfds; j++) {
        pfds[j].fd = open(argv[j + 1], O_RDONLY);
        if (pfds[j].fd == -1)
            errExit("open");

        printf("Opened \"%s\" on fd %d\n", argv[j + 1], pfds[j].fd);

        pfds[j].events = POLLIN;
    }

    /* Keep calling poll() as long as at least one file descriptor is
       open. */

    while (num_open_fds > 0) {
        int ready;

        printf("About to poll()\n");
        ready = poll(pfds, nfds, -1);
        if (ready == -1)
            errExit("poll");

        printf("Ready: %d\n", ready);

        /* Deal with array returned by poll(). */

        for (int j = 0; j < nfds; j++) {
            char buf[10];

            if (pfds[j].revents != 0) {
                printf("  fd=%d; events: %s%s%s\n", pfds[j].fd,
                        (pfds[j].revents & POLLIN)  ? "POLLIN "  : "",
                        (pfds[j].revents & POLLHUP) ? "POLLHUP " : "",
                        (pfds[j].revents & POLLERR) ? "POLLERR " : "");

                if (pfds[j].revents & POLLIN) {
                    ssize_t s = read(pfds[j].fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
                    if (s == -1)
                        errExit("read");
                    printf("    read %zd bytes: %.*s\n",
                            s, (int) s, buf);
                } else {                /* POLLERR | POLLHUP */
                    printf("    closing fd %d\n", pfds[j].fd);
                    if (close(pfds[j].fd) == -1)
                        errExit("close");
                    num_open_fds--;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    printf("All file descriptors closed; bye\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**Explanation of above code:**

This code is a bit more complex than the previous example.

`argc` is the number of arguments. `argv` is the array of arguments given to the program. argc[0] is usually the name of the program. If argc is less than 2 (which means only one argument was given), the program outputs a usage message and exits with a failure code.

`pfds = calloc(nfds, sizeof(struct pollfd));` allocates memory for an array of `struct pollfd` which is `nfds` elements long and zeroes the memory. Then there is a NULL check; if pfds is NULL, that means calloc failed (usually because the program ran out of memory), so the program prints the error with perror and exits.

The for loop opens each filename specified in `argv` and assigns it to corresponding elements of the pfd array. Then sets `.events` on each element to `POLLIN` to tell poll to check each file descriptor for whether it is ready to read

The while loop is where the actual call to poll() happens. The array of struct pollfds, `pfds`, the number of fds, `nfds`, and a timeout of -1 is passed to poll. Then the return value is checked for error (-1 is what poll return when there is an error) and if there is an error, the program prints an error message and exits. Then the number of ready file descriptors is printed.

In the second for loop inside the while loop, the program iterates over the array of `pollfd`s and checks the `.revents` field of each structure. If that field is nonzero, an event occurred on the corresponding file descriptor. The program prints the file descriptor, and the event, which can be `POLLIN` (ready for input), `POLLHUP` (hang up), or `POLLERR` (error condition). If the event was POLLIN, the file is ready to be read.

The program then reads 10 bytes into `buf`. If an error happens when reading, the program prints an error and exits. Otherwise, the program prints the number of bytes read and the contents of the buffer `buf`.

In case of error or hang up (`POLLERR`, `POLLHUP`) the program closes the file descriptor and decrements `num_open_fds`.

Finally the program says that all file descriptors are closed and exits with `EXIT_SUCCESS`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can you please explain it?